# Remove an item from User's cart after 30 minutes with PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a typical ecommerce site with a shopping cart and I want to automatically remove an item from a user's cart after 30 minutes (or some other defined time period). I'm really unsure of the best way to accomplish this. I know that there is the php sleep() function, but it seems that would be an undesirable method for waiting 30 minutes or more from a performance standpoint. I tried setting a timeout in my javascript using setTimeout() and had it call a function that would send an Ajax call to removefromcart.php along with the item's id. However, I was unsuccessful at getting that to fire at all. Below is the code used to add the item to the cart:

```
  session_start();
  require_once('../config.php');

try{ 
    $itemId = array_key_exists('itemId', $_POST) ? $_POST['itemId'] : null;

    if(!is_null($itemId)){
        if(!in_array($itemId, $_SESSION['cart'])){
            $i = count($_SESSION['cart']);
            $_SESSION['cart'][$i] = $itemId;
            $sql = "UPDATE 
                        titems 
                    SET 
                        intInactive = 1
                    WHERE 
                        intItemId = ? ";

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute([$itemId]);
            echo ("Success");
            $_SESSION['cart_count'] = count($_SESSION['cart']);
        }
    }
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    error_log($ex->getMessage());
    logError($conn, 'ADD TO CART FAILED. Error: '. $ex->getMessage());
    echo("Fail");
}
```

Here is the Javascript used to fire this event:

```
// Add Item to Cart
    $('button.addtocart').on('click', function(){
        var btnId = this.id;
        var itemId = btnId.split('-')[1];

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'Backend/addtocart.php',
            data: {itemId: itemId},
            success: function(data){
                if(data == 'Success'){
                    swal({
                        title: "Item Added!",
                        text: "my message",
                        type: "success",
                        confirmButtonText: "OK"
                    },
                    function(isConfirm){
                        if (isConfirm) {
                            $("#row-"+itemId).fadeOut("slow");  
                            location.reload();                          
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    swal({
                        title: "Error!",
                        text: "Something Went Wrong! Please Try Again.",
                        type: "error",
                        confirmButtonText: "OK"
                        });
                    }               
                } 
            })
        })
```

Javascript for removing an item when the user clicks "Remove From Cart", I'm hoping to use a similar Ajax call to accomplish my auto-removal:

```
// Remove Item From Cart
    $('#CartTable :button').on('click', function(){
        var btnId = this.id;
        var itemId = btnId.split('-')[1];

        swal({
              title: "Remove?",
              text: "Are you sure you want to remove this item from your cart?",
              type: "warning",
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonText: "Yes, remove it!",
              cancelButtonText: "No, keep it!",
              closeOnConfirm: false
            },
            function(isConfirm){
                if (isConfirm) {
                    swal("Removed!", "That item has been removed from your cart!", "success");
                    location.reload();
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'Backend/removefromcart.php',
                    data: {itemId: itemId},
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data == 'Success'){
                            swal({
                                title: "Success!",
                                text: "Item Successfully Removed From Cart",
                                type: "success",
                                confirmButtonText: "OK"
                            });
                            $("#row-"+itemId).fadeOut("slow");
                        } else {
                            swal({
                                  title: "Error!",
                                  text: "Something Went Wrong! Please Try Again.",
                                  type: "error",
                                  confirmButtonText: "OK"
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    swal("Cancelled", "Too good to let go!", "error");
                }
            }
        );
    })
```

And finally, here is the php used to actually remove the item from the cart:

```
    session_start();
    require_once('../config.php');

try{

    $itemId = array_key_exists('itemId', $_POST) ? $_POST['itemId'] : null;

    if(!is_null($itemId)){
        $i = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$i]);

        $sql = "UPDATE 
                    titems 
                SET 
                    intInactive = 0
                WHERE 
                    intItemId = ? ";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$itemId]);
        echo ("Success");
        $_SESSION['cart_count'] = count($_SESSION['cart']);
    }

} catch(Exception $ex) {
    error_log($ex->getMessage());
    logError($conn, 'REMOVE ITEM FROM CART FAILED. Error: '. $ex->getMessage());
    echo("Fail");
}
```

I'm really hoping to utilize the code that I already have in place to accomplish this task. I hope someone can help me out! Thanks.

Comment: as some one that adds stuff to shopping carts potently over months before i purchase, please dont do this.

Comment: Well, the items being sold are one-of-kind pieces, so if someone leaves an item in their cart indefinitely, it's not available for other users to view. Items are automatically removed from a user's cart when they log out already. To accommodate people like you though, I've added an 'Add to Favorites' button and a favorite items list on the user profile.

Comment: do you have datetime of when the item was added in your table ?

Comment: Not currently, but I could set something like that up.

Comment: fair call .. you need to time stamp the addition in the db, then you can run a cron job every X minutes to clear the old items

Comment: `UPDATE 
                    titems 
                SET 
                    intInactive = 0 WHERE TimeAddedField  >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);`

Comment: I've never used cron jobs. I've heard of them though. Is it a plugin? Can you point me towards a good resource for getting started with them?

Comment: cron jobs are an OS application in *nix